# Show a loading animation on a Oracle ApEx IR report prior to loading

Tags: plugins, loading, oracle-apex

I am attempting to use the following loading animation plugin located here:

[loading plugin animation](http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/loading-icon_81.html)

but on a Interactive Report (IR) that takes about 5 - 10 seconds to load.

So basically, when the user clicks on a menu option to run this IR, I would like to show this loading animation, indicating that the report is preparing to load and then once the IR is loaded, hide this loading animation.

How can I achieve this? My loading animation turns on, once the report has actually loaded, and not prior to actually loading.

I have selected "Fire on Page Load" and even used the event "Page Load" but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this going from my menu system that kicks of the report. Using a jQuery selector dynamic action together with the loading plugin on Page 0 of my application, this is now working as required.